# Non principal discriminant ideal

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, discriminant

> Is there an extension of number fields $L/K$ such that the discriminant ideal $d_{L/K}$ isn't principal?

With discriminant I mean [relative discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant_of_an_algebraic_number_field#Relative_discriminant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this is fairly common.

Let $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{-7})$ and $L=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt[3]{-7})$.

Then the relative discriminant of $L/K$ is the ideal $(3,1+\sqrt[3]{-7})$.

Proof by Sage:

```
K.<a> = NumberField(x^3+7)
t = K['t'].gen()
L.<b>=K.extension(t^2 +3)
L.relative_discriminant()
```

[image]